# circle based lists within drop and drag - responsive

Tags: jquery, css, drag-and-drop, responsive-design

I have the following drop and drag setup which is working howver the sizing of the list icons is fixed so when the browser is smaller (tablet / mobile) the items are not didplaying as evenly as they are for a desktop.

How can I go about making the sizing percentages instead?

The full code is online with the demo on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/elogicmedia/rKUkF/4/

Thankyou

JS

```
    circle_radius = 200;
$links = $('nav ul.gallery li a');
total_links = $links.size();
$links.each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('data-index',index);
    animateCircle($(this), 1);
});
$('ul.gallery > li a').hover(function() {
    animateCircle($(this), 1.1);
}, function() {
    animateCircle($(this), 1);

});

function animateCircle($link, expansion_scale) {
    index = $link.attr('data-index');
    radians = 2*Math.PI*(index/total_links);
    x = -(Math.sin(radians)*circle_radius*expansion_scale);
    y = -(Math.cos(radians)*circle_radius*expansion_scale);
    $link.animate({
        top: x+'px',
        left: y+'px'
    }, 200);
}
```

CSS

```
a {
position: absolute;
text-decoration: none;
width:98px;
height:98px;
border-radius:50%;
line-height:1.5em;
text-align:center;
font-family: helvetica, arial;
background-color: #C0D9D9;
```

}